# como alinear los link a la izquierda y derecha con bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente menu creado con boostrapt :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>example video</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<br>
<iframe class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DK_0jXPuIr0"   frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- 
Recursos usados :
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/


-->
</body>
</html>
```

y los link esta localizados a la derecha ( mia )  me gustaria mandar uno a la izquierda y otro a la derecha, alguien sabe como podria hacerlo?

Por ejemplo el link house a la izquierda y los otros a la derecha (edito)

Comment: Cuales links ? los del menú ? quieres que queden en alineación horizontal ? por favor explícate mejor

Comment: Listo ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Creo que aun no es lo suficientemente claro, tome en cuenta que los items del nav, en pantallas (referenció el tamaño con las clases de bootstrap) `md-lg` se ven en la barra, pero en pantallas `xs-sm` se ocultan, quedando en un menú desplegable.

Comment: @Michael Bootstrap 4 incorpora clases para manipular comportamientos dependiendo la resolución de pantalla, por lo cual eso no es problema en este caso...o te refieres a en que resolución quiere mostrarlos en ese orden ?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez gracias por la aclaración, y si esa era mi pregunta.

Comment: Bueno @Michael esperemos que llegue el OP y nos aclare en que resolución quiere ese cambio si desktop o movil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootstrap** te provee clases para lograr lo que quieres, solo es cuestión de conocerlas poco a poco, acá te dejo el ejemplo funcional donde podrás observas con detenimiento las clases que he usado (`flex-row`, `px-2`, `mr-auto`, `w-100`).

Para más información podrías visitar [Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <title>example video</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row w-100">
      <li class="nav-item px-2 mr-auto active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-2">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<br>
<iframe class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DK_0jXPuIr0"   frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- 
Recursos usados :
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/


-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me ayudo mucho :) y lo siento si mi pregunta fue algo nuuf pero no conozco complamente la version 4